# Multi site Image cache issue

Tags: drush, caching

actually i am new to drupal and i have migrated my drupal site from 8 to 9. This site is multi site, every thing is working fine but the issue is related to the images. When i cleared the cache using drush cmd and load first domain site(i.e example.com) getting all the images, when load on the second domain site(i.e examplelocal.com) not getting all the images. When i cleared the cache again load second domain site(i.e examplelocal.com) first this time all the images getting, When i load the first domain site(i.e example.com) not getting all the images. After clearing cache, which site is loaded first getting all the images the other site is not getting. Presently i am working on local. I tried to clear cache using the drush cr specific url. But it is not working. Could you help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a cache layer on top of Drupal? Like Varnish?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No, i don't have

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding domain module and enabling it with the domain configuration which is the sub-module. Thanks for the help